# output of this java program is slightly off?

Tags: java

**Java Code:**

```
public class Car {

    //variables
    int myStartMiles;
    int myEndMiles;
    double myGallonsUsed;
    int odometerReading;
    double gallons;

    //constructors
    public Car(int odometerReading) {
        this.myStartMiles = odometerReading;
        this.myEndMiles = myStartMiles;
    }

    //methods
    public void fillUp(int odometerReading, double gallons) {
        this.myEndMiles = odometerReading;
        this.gallons = gallons;
    }

    public double calculateMPG() {
        int a = (this.myEndMiles - this.myStartMiles);
        return ((a) / (this.gallons));
    }

    public void resetMPG() {
        myGallonsUsed = 0;
        this.myStartMiles = myEndMiles;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int startMiles = 15;
        Car auto = new Car(startMiles);

        System.out.println("New car odometer reading: " + startMiles);
        auto.fillUp(150, 8);
        System.out.println("Miles per gallon: " + auto.calculateMPG());
        System.out.println("Miles per gallon: " + auto.calculateMPG());
        auto.resetMPG();
        auto.fillUp(350, 10);
        auto.fillUp(450, 20);
        System.out.println("Miles per gallon: " + auto.calculateMPG());
        auto.resetMPG();
        auto.fillUp(603, 25.5);
        System.out.println("Miles per gallon: " + auto.calculateMPG()); 
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get this to work, but I can't get the desired output.

The desired results are:

```
New car odometer reading: 15
Miles per gallon: 16.875
Miles per gallon: 16.875
Miles per gallon: 10.0
Miles per gallon: 6.0
```

I'm getting:

```
New car odometer reading: 15
Miles per gallon: 16.875
Miles per gallon: 16.875
Miles per gallon: 15.0
Miles per gallon: 6.0
```

Could you tell me what is wrong with the code? I am trying to manually run it by hand on paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `fillUp` method. Specifically this line:

```
this.gallons = gallons;
```

Should be:

```
this.gallons += gallons;
```

Since you are assigning instead of adding, the output is wrong in the third case because:

```
auto.fillUp(350, 10);
auto.fillUp(450, 20);
```

Sets `gallons` to `10` and then overwrites it with `20` instead of adding `10`, and then adding `20` for a total of `30`.

**EDIT:** You will also need `gallons = 0;` in your `resetMPG` method. Currently you set `myGallonsUsed = 0`, but that variable is otherwise unused, so I don't know why you are doing this.

Comment: this will not work since this.gallons  will contain first `8` then `10` then `20` so total `38`.

Comment: @user1659362 @AmitD That's because the `reset` method resets `myGallonsUsed` instead of `gallons`. I think this is an error, since `myGallonsUsed` is not used anywhere else. Either way, the way you are handling `gallons` currently is certainly an error.